# Update actions.json withouth using gactions CLI

Tags: actions-on-google

I've built an Action on Google using the Actions SDK. I want to be able to update the actions.json programmatically on my server. I don't want to have to use the Assistant CLI. Is there a REST API or some other way of updating that file?

Comment: If I get an access token from the Assistant CLI, then I can make a post request to https://actions.googleapis.com/v2/agents/<projectId>:batchUpdateAllDraftActionPackages
I'm having trouble generating a valid access token.
Voiceflow seems to be able to. They direct users through an oauth2 sign in for Assistant CLI. The user gets an auth code that they give to Voiceflow. Voiceflow turns that into an access token on their server.
I assume it's related to "Step 5" here. When I try it, I get a message saying my client is invalid
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server

Comment: I'm guessing that Voiceflow has a hosted copy of gactions on their server that they use to make the requests wrapped in a REST API.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to sniff the communication between Google and the actions cli.

**Updating the action**

Here is the `curl` request which you can use. Don't forget to add your `Bearer` (authorization) and after `--data-binary` you will include your `actions.json`. The last thing is, to change the endpoint URL at the end with your action id (replace `testskill`).

```
curl 
-H 'Host: actions.googleapis.com' 
-H 'content-type: application/json' 
-H 'authorization: Bearer AuthorisationKeyAsRandomStrings' 
-H 'user-agent: Gactions-CLI/2.2.4 (darwin; amd64; dev/NsZwRCulTKhlPxMfp)' 
--data-binary '{"localizedActionPackages":{"de":{"actions":[{"description":"Default welcome intent","fulfillment":{"conversationName":"testskill"},"intent":{"name":"actions.intent.MAIN","trigger":{"queryPatterns":["sprechen mit test skill"]}},"name":"MAIN"},{"description":"test intent","fulfillment":{"conversationName":"testskill"},"intent":{"name":"test_intent","parameters":[{"name":"color","type":"org.schema.type.Color"}],"trigger":{"queryPatterns":["suchen ein $org.schema.type.Color:color schuhe","kaufen ein $org.schema.type.Color:color shuhe","kaufen"]}},"name":"Test"},{"description":"ciao","fulfillment":{"conversationName":"testskill"},"intent":{"name":"ciao_intent","trigger":{"queryPatterns":["ciao","bye","pa"]}},"name":"Ciao"}],"conversations":{"testskill":{"name":"testskill","url":"https://ae8e6xx.ngrok.io/testskill"}},"locale":"de"}},"name":"agents/testskill"}' 
--compressed 'https://actions.googleapis.com/v2/agents/testskill:batchUpdateAllDraftActionPackages'
```

But there is no guarantee, that this will work in the future because Google can change the endpoint without notifying anybody. So I recommend to stick with actions cli.

**Obtaining token without gactions CLI**

You need to visit this url:
https://accounts.google.com/signin/oauth/oauthchooseaccount?access_type=offline&client_id=237807841406-o6vu1tjkq8oqjub8jilj6vuc396e2d0c.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob&response_type=code&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Factions.builder&state=state&o2v=1&as=ZmeGyvTUA3FLgRPS1_rd1A&flowName=GeneralOAuthFlow

After authorization you will get the token. This needs to be send with another curl request. You need to replace `PlaceYourUrlEncodedTokenHere` with your token, but it needs to be url encoded.

```
curl 
-H 'Host: accounts.google.com' 
-H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 
-H 'authorization: Basic MjM3ODA3ODQxNDA2LW82dnUxdGprcThvcWp1YjhqaWxqNnZ1YzM5NmUyZDBjLmFwcHMuZ29vZ2xldXNlcmNvbnRlbnQuY29tOjZ1TlVQakZvd3pVRThTbGlWWlg2a2VZMA==' 
-H 'user-agent: Go-http-client/2.0' 
--data-binary "code=PlaceYourUrlEncodedTokenHere&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob" 
--compressed 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token'
```

After that you will receive json response from google which conatins `access_token`. This you will add to your request as `Bearer`.

Comment: Yeah, think that should word. Still depends on the CLI to get a valid token, is that right?

Comment: That would be great. Where did value "authorization: Basic MjM3ODA3ODQx..." come from? Once I exchange the auth code for an access/refresh token, I assumed I needed the client id + client secret + refresh token to get new access tokens. And that the client secret is something I can't know, as it's embedded in the gactions CLI.Is that not the case?

Comment: @reidreid46 you can create your own google console project where you will obtain your secrets. Than you need to also specify scope which is: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/actions.builder`.
You can play with it on https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground

Comment: @BjørsonÅlmer have you managed this yourself, I tried to make a token to authenticate with the APIs for publishing and it says the method doesn't exist when I call it

Comment: Also when I get the playground to list available operations, none are shown. Makes me think APIs are tied to the client ID so other than using your method of offline token generation and then using the access token from that you can't use the APIs directly. Disappointing.

Comment: @Peter Fox I played around and you are right, they are blocking all access to their api if you are not using cli. So you cant use your own app, you have to use cli or access tokens from cli, to get it work with curl

Comment: @BjørsonÅlmer do you know how to refresh the access token received?

Comment: @BjørsonBjørson am getting this message https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75830062/access-blocked-assistant-cli-s-request-is-invalid

Comment: @RameshS sorry, this was done a long time ago, and I have no clue. This project ended for me and I am not interested anymore in google actions.

Answer (score 0):

Since yesterday i'm having a problem with actions cli, when i try to update my actions.json i have this error with oauth

Error 401: disabled_client
The OAuth client was disabled.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0dkd.png)