# Access blocked: Assistant CLI’s request is invalid

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, actions-on-google

This Questions already asked but that is not solve my issue.

I created a project under `Google Action Console` and made a test action package for custom app. I want to try uploading the action package I have using `gactions`. Am using below commend

```
gactions test --action_package action.json --project my-project-381534
```

Am getting below result in terminal:

```
Pushing the app for the Assistant for testing...
Gactions needs access to your Google account. Please copy & paste the URL below into a web browser and follow the instructions there. Then copy and paste the authorization code from the browser back here.
Visit this URL: 
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&client_id=237807841406-o6vu1tjkq8oqjub8jilj6vuc396e2d0c.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob&response_type=code&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Factions.builder&state=state 
Enter authorization code:
```

When ever I copy paste the `URL` in browser it is showing `Access blocked: Assistant CLI’s request is invalid` message.

[image]

> **I have added the emails in `OAuth consent screen` and I have tried the OOB as well. That also not help to solve this issue**

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: can you please try the steps you mentioned in private/incognito browser window?

Comment: Hi @BihagKashikar Thanks for the replay. I tried in in private/incognito 
 am getting this https://ibb.co/smw6ZQx

Comment: @BihagKashikar: we should provide any permission to Assistant CLI’s ?

Comment: Make sure that you are logged in to the correct Google account. The account should have access to the Google Action Console and the project you are trying to test.Try opening the URL in an incognito window.Check if there are any ad-blockers or firewalls that may be blocking the URL. You may need to temporarily disable them to complete the authorization flow.
If none of the above steps work, you can try regenerating the authorization code by running the gactions test command again. This will generate a new URL and authorization code.

Comment: Hi @itIsNaz thanks for the suggestions, I will check the steps.